# Link Azure DevOps CI and CD yaml pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

I created two yaml pipelines.

1. CI yaml pipeline which produces artifact and upload the artifact to Nexus repository.
2. CD yaml pipeline which I want to design to download artifact from Nexus Repository and deploy to multiple environments.

When I use the Classic Release Pipeline, I can link the published build artifact from the CI pipeline.
[image]
[image]

But when I use YAML CD pipeline, I don't know how to link the CI pipeline so that I can pull the $(Build.BuildNumber) from the CI build. This is what I have tried so far..

```
resources:
 pipelines:
  - pipeline: test
    source: DevOps_CI_YAML_Nexus
```

and tried to use this variable to get the BuildNumber from the CI build.
$(resources.pipeline.test.Build.BuildNumber) but looks like this syntax is wrong.

Could anyone share if you know how to get this to work?

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: `$(Build.TriggeredBy.BuildNumber)` might be what you are looking for if your CD pipeline is automatically triggered by CI run. Documented [HERE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)

Comment: Not get your latest information, are the following answers helpful to you?

Answer (score 1):

To link published build artifacts from CI pipeline, you can use a built-in task called "download build artifacts".

[image]

In the task settings, you can choose an artifacts by its project, build pipeline and build version, just like what you can do in Classic UI release pipeline.

Here is an example script of the task:

```
- task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@0
  name: {task name}
  inputs:
    buildType: 'specific'
    project: '{project id}'
    pipeline: '{pipeline id}'
    buildVersionToDownload: 'latest'
    downloadType: 'single'
    artifactName: '{artifact name}'
    downloadPath: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)'
```

And the task has an output variable `BuildNumber`. You can use `{taskname}.BuildNumber` to get the number of the build which the artifact was downloaded from.

Answer (score 0):

It looks that this info is not avialable in variables (yet). I tried these variables:

```yaml
- script: |
    echo '$(Build.TriggeredBy.BuildNumber)'!
    echo '$(Build.TriggeredBy.BuildId)'!
    echo '$(Build.TriggeredBy.DefinitionId)'!
    echo '$(Build.TriggeredBy.DefinitionName)'!
    echo '$(Build.TriggeredBy.ProjectID)'!
    echo '$(Build.BuildNumber)'!
    echo '$(Build.RequestedFor)'!
    echo '$(Build.RequestedForEmail)'!
    echo '$(Build.RequestedForId)'!
```

and this is what I got:

```
$(Build.TriggeredBy.BuildNumber)!
$(Build.TriggeredBy.BuildId)!
$(Build.TriggeredBy.DefinitionId)!
$(Build.TriggeredBy.DefinitionName)!
$(Build.TriggeredBy.ProjectID)!
20200901.12!
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.TFS!
!
00000002-0000-8888-8000-000000000000!
```

So I got meaningful value only for `$(Build.BuildNumber)`.

So to get build number of your pipeline trigger you may use REST API:

```yaml
variables:
  devopsAccount : 'thecodemanual'
  projectName : 'DevOps Manual'

steps:
- pwsh: |
    # Get a build info
    $uri = "https://dev.azure.com/$(devopsAccount)/$(projectName)/_apis/build/builds/$(Build.BuildId)?api-version=6.0-preview.6&expand=all"

    Write-Host $uri

    # Invoke the REST call
    $result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Get -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"}

    $buildNumber = $result.triggerInfo.version
    Write-Host $buildNumber

    echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=triggeredByBuildNumber]$buildNumber"
- script: |
    echo '$(triggeredByBuildNumber)'!
```

With this approach I retrieved `20200901.14` which is correct value of my build trigger.

And trigger info has more details:

```
    "triggerInfo": {
        "artifactType": "Pipeline",
        "alias": "test",
        "projectId": "4fa6b279-3db9-4cb0-aab8-e06c2ad550b2",
        "pipelineTriggerType": "PipelineCompletion",
        "source": "kmadof.dm-so-46",
        "pipelineId": "3320",
        "version": "20200901.14"
    },
```

if you need some.